# does linux fsync will sync file's xattr?

Tags: linux, fsync, xattr

From man fsync(2), it will sync the file's metadata, which i think it's something list in stat.
What's about file's xattr? does it belongs to metadata?
We did a test,
write a file, and set 6 xattrs, then do fsync,
then change 1 xattr value, and do fsync again(use 0.2s).
We think the second fsync should be fast, but it's not(use 0.16s).

Answer (score 0):

As my colleague said, it's reasonable, bc the mininum size of disk operation is a sector, which usally 512 bytes, so there is no difference when i update 1 xattr, or 6 xattrs.